# Can I allow front-end users to PUBLISH articles in specific categories?

Tags: articles, permissions

Can I allow users to PUBLISH articles in certain categories without giving them the ability to publish to any category. It seems that they can create articles but then the article requires someone with PUBLISH permission to actually publish the article.

Answer (score 2):

We have a feature called **Access Control List (ACL)**, with this
you can create
 a user groups and assign them permissions to
access, create, edit or delete 
content or modify certains parts 
of your site like articles, categories, modules,
 global configurations, etc.

For example, we have the user group **"Author"**, in the screenshot you can see a
 category called **"Blog"**, in the **"Permissions"** tab we can allow or denied actions.

[image]

Here some docs:
https://docs.joomla.org/ACL

Here a full example:
https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Access_Control_List_Tutorial

Best Regards!